# How to send current screen as a page link in chat in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. I want to develop a functionality where there will be more(3 dots) option on top right corner if user clicks on it share in chat option will come and if user selects that option that page will be send as a link in chat . Please not we have already implemented chat functionality. Please guide me. The link should appear in chat as below :[image]